# Exclusive Commands in discord.py?

Tags: python, command

I want to make some exclusive commands for premium users. How can I set that only certain people can use a command?

Comment: You need to have a database that stores your users. And have some way of specifying which users are 'premium'. Once a commands comes through just grab which user sent the command, lookup that user in the database and see if they are a premium member. If so run the command if not ignore it.